# Qt hyperlink for C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a link that I am adding into a Qt Window that I created and I want it to be a hyperlink that is click-able by the user.

Also how exactly does the layout work for Qt? 
is this right to assume?

```
      layout->addWidget(name_of_widget_to_add, row, column, width, height);
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask 2 questions. The hyperlink topic is totally different from the layout question.

Answer (score 3):

The `QLabel` widget supports HTML code.

```
myLabel->setText("<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>Click</a>");
myLabel->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can add a widget with a clickable link :

```
QLabel* l = new QLabel("<a href='http://example.com'>example.com</a>");
l->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
```

And the way to add that widget depends on the type of layout you're using.

For a QGridLayout that would be :

```
QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget * widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn,
                       int rowSpan, int columnSpan,
                       Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)
```

Which is close to what you posted, but not quite the same.